# Sonoff can't enter DIY Mode

Tags: http, automation, iot, sensors

I have a SONOFF Pow Origin device and I want to enter in the DIY Mode to control it over the HTTP. So I power up the board, press for 5 seconds the button, connect to the ITEAD network(on the site it says that it should have a password but mine doesn't have one), and then go to https://10.10.7.1 and now this URL isn't working. What I do wrong? I have updated the firmware in the app.